# How to forward proxy credentials

Tags: browser, proxy, http-proxy

My development group works at a remote office which requires us to VPN into the corporate network to get access to any company resources. The corporate network is designed to forward NTLM credentials to all websites.

This causes massive headaches for us, because we all have MacBooks and therefore do not have NTLM credentials stored, so whenever the above happens (and fails), we have to type in our ID/PW again. This happens literally 20+ times a day, and if we disconnect from the VPN and reconnect, we have to do it 20+ times yet again. No exaggeration, I have had to type my ID/PW into a browser window >50x in a single day on multiple occasions, and everyone on my 12-person team has had days that were just as bad. Clearly, this is not a positive experience. Corporate IT officially does not support OSX, so they are no help whatsoever.

What can we do to improve our experience? Like, isn't there a way to run a local proxy that will always forward NTLM credentials to any internal corporate website that asks for them? Or is there a way we can make our browsers smarter with what sites get routed through the proxy?

Comment: NTLM is an opaque (doesn't leak credentials) auth protocol, so you can't store and forward NTLM credentials.  I don't understand "The corporate network is designed to forward NTLM credentials to all websites".  Do you mean the network has a proxy that requests NTLM authentication for all websites?  Normally we see this sort of problem (too many login dialogs) occur when a client browser is not configured to use a proxy, and the proxy is intercepting the connection and asking for authentication.  In this case, the client thinks every different web server is asking for credentials.

Comment: If we use a Windows machine on the corporate network, we get asked to log into the proxy the first time we hit a service that requires it. After that, we never get prompted. On our Macs over the VPN, we get asked by every individual server that requires it. In the 20+ example above, when in the corporate office, that number is 1. We are using a proxy.pac, and none of these 20+ servers are in the proxy.pac file. That file already has >750 exceptions in it. Both environments use the same proxy.pac.

Comment: Is it possible the windows machines are configured to use the proxy whereas the VPN machines are being intercepted?  We see this problem all the time with authentication at the proxy for intercepted connections. Because the browsers think they are talking directly to the servers, they won't re-use credentials from one server on another, and loading a single page can cause multiple login prompts due to being comprised of resources from many servers.

Comment: That certainly may be the case. How do we fix/address that?

Comment: The first thing is to verify if this is indeed the case.  If so the best fix is to actually configure the VPN clients to use the proxy explicitly.  Yes, this can be a pain.  You may be able to deploy proxy auto-detect to ease this pain.

Comment: That is what we already have in place. We do use the proxy explicitly using a proxy.pac file.